# Date column arithmetic in PostgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-arithmetic

I have two tables that look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (user_id int, the_date date);
CREATE TABLE table2 (user_id int, the_date date, something_else real);
```

I am writing a query that looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE foo AS 
 SELECT t1.user_id
 , (t1.the_date - (t2.the_date - t1.the_date)::int) start_date
 FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 
 where t1.user_id=t2.user_id
 ;
```

When I run the above query, I get the following error displayed on the psql console:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
> LINE 1: ...the_date - (t2.the_date - t1.the_date)::int)  $1 ...
>
>                                                              ^
> ```

The second column in the query result is to show a date which is `N days BEFORE` the date in table1, where N is the difference (in days) between the date in table2 and table1.

Note: `table2` will always have has later dates than the dates in `table1`.

How can I perform this date calculation and store the result as a new column alias in my query?

I am using PG 8.4.

Comment: I'm getting a different error while trying to execute your `CREATE` query:

`ERROR:  "user_id" is ambiguous
LINE 6: CREATE TABLE foo AS SELECT user_id, (t1.the_date - (t2.the_d...
                                   ^
`

EDIT: after adding `t1.` before `user_id` query works fine. PostgreSQL 8.4

Comment: @LisMorski: I have corrected the example I gave. It was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to table-qualify `t1.user_id` to disambiguate. Plus other adjustments:

```
CREATE TABLE foo AS 
SELECT user_id, (t1.the_date - (t2.the_date - t1.the_date)) AS start_date
FROM   table1 t1
JOIN   table2 t2 USING (user_id);
```

- Subtracting two dates yields integer. Cast was redundant.
- Don't omit the `AS` keyword for [column aliases](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES) - while it's generally OK to omit `AS` for table aliases. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-SELECT-LIST)

  > You can omit `AS`, but only if the desired output name does not match
  >   any PostgreSQL keyword ([see Appendix C](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html)). For protection against
  >   possible future keyword additions, it is recommended that you always
  >   either write `AS` or double-quote the output name.)
- Joining tables with a `USING` clause only keeps *one* instance of the joining columns(s) (`user_id` in this case) in the result set and you don't have to table-qualify it any more.

Comment: I found out the problem. It turned out that alias name I was using `start_date` was the same as one of the arguments in the function (the $1 in the error message should have alerted me!).