# MS Access Query returns only matching data between two queries

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am creating a query for three table (1 master table contains n numbers, 2 Daily Production, 3 Daily Sales)

But queries returning only that data which available in all tables.

Please help me sorting this issue

Comment: You need to give us more information.  Are the tables related? What data do you want back, from which table? If they are then you need to take a look at joins:  Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198084%28v=office.15%29.aspx.

Comment: What you want is a LEFT JOIN:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14260860/multiple-left-joins-on-multiple-tables-in-one-query