# How to count rows for groups with a given member?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, aggregate

I have the following table `members`:

```
album_id | user_id
-------------------
1          1
1          2
1          4
2          1
2          4
4          1
5          3
```

with a unique constraint on `(album_id, user_id)`.

I'd like to get the count of how many users there are per gallery, but only if the gallery contains a given user.

So for instance if I get all rows with `user_id = 4`, I'd like to get a result like

```
album_id | count(user_id)
-------------------------
1         3
2         2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT album_id, count(*) AS ct
FROM   tbl t
JOIN   tbl t1 USING (album_id)
WHERE  t.user_id = 4
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;  -- optional
```

I chose this form, out of many possible solutions, because it can use an index on `(user_id)`.

For best performance, you have two indexes: one on `(user_id, album_id)`, and another one on `(album_id)` (or a multicolumn index with `album` as leading column). See:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)

Assuming `user_id` is `NOT NULL`, so `count(*)` is equivalent, but faster. See:

- [Postgres: count(*) vs count(id)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/41097/3684)

Comment: does it need the "AS ct" part?

Comment: The column alias is optional, but recommended. Choose what you like. Else you get a default name, `count` in this case. But it's recommended to include the `AS` keyword, unlike with table aliases. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11543614/939860